# d3 Axis Ticks Not Updating

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have taken the example from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245) and I am modifying it slightly so that the graph is drawn when the page loads and the line is drawn when a user selects a file from a jsTree. That is all working fine and the data is plotted correctly. But, the tick marks remain 0 to 1 on the Y axis and 6 PM to .001 on the x axis. I can't figure out how to update them based on the new data. I am just learning js and d3 so I'm sure the knowledge gap is the issue here. But, after a couple hours of being unable to resolve the issue, it was time to ask.

```
 <script>
  var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");
  var svg;

window.onload = function(){
   svg = d3.select("#MainDiv").append("svg")
    .attr("id","myGraph")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
     .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");
}

function updateGraph(filename){

  d3.xhr("http://127.0.0.1:8080/Data/TreeData/getGraphData?filename="+filename, function(error,data){


  var data = d3.tsv.parse(data.responseText);
  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
  var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

   svg.selectAll("y axis")
            .call(yAxis)

   svg.selectAll("x axis")
            .call(xAxis);


  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));


  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});   
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector for the axes elements is wrong. If you want to select by class, prefix the name of the class with a dot:

```
svg.selectAll(".y.axis")
        .call(yAxis)
svg.selectAll(".x.axis")
        .call(xAxis);
```

Comment: Thanks, and note I also had to move the svg.selectAll... code to be called after the domain updates. Works fine now.